# Scalable outline for any shape with THREE.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I should start off by saying I'm new to WebGL and the THREE library. I'm trying to achieve:

- Add 2D shapes to a scene (squares, triangles, circles etc)
- Shapes can have any size and position
- Shapes should have no fill and an outline that scales depending on the shape size

I tried using wireframe:

```
const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(40, 40, 0);

const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
  color: 0xff0000,
  wireframe: true,
});

const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
scene.add(mesh);
```

The above renders the following:

- A 3D box with no depth
- A non-scalable outline with a set width of 1
- A cross through the box

I also tried the same but plotting the points for a 2D shape:

```
const shapeSize = 100;
const x = -shapeSize / 2;
const y = -shapeSize / 2;

const square = new THREE.Shape();

square.moveTo(x, y);
square.lineTo(x + shapeSize, y);
square.lineTo(x + shapeSize, y + shapeSize);
square.lineTo(x, y + shapeSize);
square.lineTo(x, y);

const geometry = new THREE.ShapeGeometry(square);

const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
  color: 0xff0000,
  wireframe: true,
});

const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
this.scene.add(mesh);
```

The above renders:

- A 2D box
- A non-scalable outline with a set width of 1
- A single diagonal line through the box

Can anyone demonstrate how to achieve the scalable outline of just the 2D shape? Do I need to use a shader?

Comment: I read this but i don't understand what you want. Could you illustrate this with an image?

Comment: @pailhead Literally just a hollow box with an outline. Or a hollow circle with an outline. Wireframe is always a width of 1, but I want an outline that corresponds to the size of the shape. I can create a graphic if it's still not clear.

Comment: Looks like he needs to combine something like [this](https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_geometry_text_shapes) with [that](https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_lines_fat.html).

Comment: @prisoner849 Yeah potentially. Fat lines would do it. Are you able to provide an answer with an example of how this would be done?

Comment: I'm actually really surprised that this doesn't seem like a super easy thing to do. You can create complex 3D shapes and do crazy animations, but it seems hard to create a simple 2D shape with an outline.

Comment: Based on your description that you're making a 2D image and given your requirements of outlines it seems like you'd be better off using canvas 2d.

Answer (score 2):

I've just used the code from the example of fat lines:

```js
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
camera.position.set(0, 0, 10);
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
  antialias: true
});
renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
renderer.setClearColor(0x000000, 0.0);
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

var points = [
  -5, 4, 0, 5, 4, 0, 5, -4, 0, -5, -4, 0, -5, 4, 0
]

var geometry = new THREE.LineGeometry();
geometry.setPositions(points);

matLine = new THREE.LineMaterial({

  color: 0x00ffff,
  linewidth: 5, // in pixels
  dashed: false

});

line = new THREE.Line2(geometry, matLine);
line.computeLineDistances();
line.scale.set(1, 1, 1);
scene.add(line);

render();

function render() {
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
  matLine.resolution.set(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>

<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/WebGL.js"></script>

<script src='https://threejs.org/examples/js/lines/LineSegmentsGeometry.js'></script>
<script src='https://threejs.org/examples/js/lines/LineGeometry.js'></script>

<script src='https://threejs.org/examples/js/lines/LineMaterial.js'></script>

<script src='https://threejs.org/examples/js/lines/LineSegments2.js'></script>
<script src='https://threejs.org/examples/js/lines/Line2.js'></script>
<script src='https://threejs.org/examples/js/lines/Wireframe.js'></script>
```

Comment: Really appreciate your help but as I said I'm new to WebGL and Three.js and this answer looks like it needs substantial reverse engineering for me to understand and use it since you're importing 9 external scripts. Would you be able to post a more concise example?

Comment: @Coop I haven't used this type of lines before, so I'm not an expert in it. Original example uses more than 9 external scripts :) If it is not what you're looking for, I will delete my answer.

Comment: The result is visually pretty much what I'm after. But due to the nature of this answer being split over 9 complicated external scripts, I'm unable to get this working in my scenario...

Comment: This type of lines is not a part of the core of the framework. That's why there are so many external scripts :)